# how can I write a picker function that picks only properties (without repeating the types in generic type constraints) in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to find a neat function that picks only properties of interest in a type (not only in type, but also masks away other properties during runtime).

Currently my best solution is:

```js
export function picker<T extends {}, K extends keyof T>(
    keys: K[],
): (m: T) => Pick<T, K> {
    return (m: T) => {
        const result: Partial<Pick<T, K>> = {};
        for (const key of keys) {
            result[key] = m[key];
        }
        return result as Pick<T, K>;
    };
}

interface Test {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    hobbies: string[];
}

const t: Test = {
    name: "yj",
    age: 12,
    hobbies: ["shopping"],
};

const pickTest = picker<Test, "name">(["name"]); //I want to remove the repetition in writing name twice here
// pickTest(t) should be of type `{name: string}` only
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you'd like minimal changes to your function (changing only the typings and not the implementation), I'd be inclined to move the `T` generic from the outer function to the function it returns.  The outer function accepts a parameter `keys` of type `K[]`, so it can infer `K` easily, but it is impossible to infer `T` because there are no values of type `T` to look at.  In your current version, you have to manually specify `T`, which you want to avoid.  So we can move `T` into the returned function, since that function accepts a value `m` of type `T` and `T` can be inferred from there.

Of course we can no longer write `K extends keyof T` when `T` is not in scope.  Instead, we can say `K extends PropertyKey` (it's a key-like type) and then `T extends Record<K, any>`.  Instead of constraining `K` to be a key of `T`, we're constraining `T` to have  a property at key `K`.

It looks like this:

```
function picker<K extends PropertyKey>(
  keys: K[],
): <T extends Record<K, any>>(m: T) => Pick<T, K> {
  return <T extends Record<K, any>>(m: T) => {
    const result: Partial<Pick<T, K>> = {};
    for (const key of keys) {
      result[key] = m[key];
    }
    return result as Pick<T, K>;
  };
}
```

Now we can call `picker` and `pickTest` without having to specify any type parameters manually; the compiler infers them just fine:

```
const pickTest = picker(["name"]);
const justName = pickTest(t); // Pick<Test, "name">
console.log(justName); // {name : "yj"}
justName.name.toUpperCase();
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABxhA1gUwE4B4DSimAHlJmACYDOiACtnMjlAJ76YsB8AFALABQiRFhZUAXInwBtALoAaAQEoJuACpFS5aogBKmCHGwUCcxAEMwXHgFsJqxYgC8nOmnRrT+FwG8BQ7JhQINhIahpklDR6BkYm5pacNnYOzoi+gkKIBmBUUIgBVCAANlAStGbYsGZFuLRuHpKJTmkAvgDcfpnAhojc2bnCHIhwwIOiDumZmQXFUFIiMs3W8xwyHRlCLZ3+gcFIMyXmNHUYDV7rm+tb-AIwYGTYwGYQmIiqmAOTiGBm1pgSuWwdwA5hdzMD-t8QNYAEY4MEACzgMJhMA+AKgQLAwNkVwEAn6eVKbw+eUcaU6Pz+EgARCwAFY0hQZMwQiQARgATMyhEiUWjxIgpDSqEjkKhsTT5AJ2vj+ISUG53gNyagMDhuMKqZgpYp1gr6SBcgA5X6vVVK0ncKB6xAAejtrlOyqgphp2ppnAJCCocCKmAAdEU4MDuIaTWbbQ60trELSGTTruGoKa-gHtQGoHAAKrinAAYTMVEw3D1QA)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed I only get `name` as property in justName. A little downside is that, there is no autocompletion at `picker(["name" /*no autocompletion when enumerating property names*/]);`. Though the type system will have compilation error if invalid property names are provided at later stage. I guess there is no better answer within the capabilities of the current version of typescript. Thanks again!